# PowerBI Report or SQL Query Grouping Data Spanning Columns

Tags: sql, powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I'm wracking my brain trying to figure this out.  I have a dataset / table that looks like this:

```
ID | Person1 | Person2 | Person3 | EffortPerPerson
01 | Bob     | Ann     | Frank   | 2
02 | Frank   | Bob     | Joe     | 3
03 | Ann     | Joe     | Beth    | 1
```

I'm trying add up "Effort" for each person.  For example, Bob is 2+3, Joe is 3+1, etc.  My goal is to produce a PowerBI scatter plot showing total Effort for each person.

In a perfect world, the query shouldn't care how many "Person" fields there are.  It should just count up the Effort value for every row that the individual's name appears.

I thought GROUP BY would work, but obviously that's only for one column, and I can't wrap my head around how to make nested queries work here.

Any one have any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Use the Unpivot transform. Try and get Person1 etc. into rows then you can just add it all up normally.

Answer (score 0):

As Nick suggested, you should go with the Unpivot transformation. Go to Edit Queries and select Transform tab:
[image]

Select columns you want to transform in rows, open dropdown menu under Unpivot Columns and select "Unpivot Only Selected Columns":

[image]

And that's it! Power BI will aggregate values for you:

[image]